# Botframework-WebChat - Why doesn't it work with Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've got the webchat working correctly in Chrome but not in IE.
My app is an Angular website using WebChat to connect to my bot.

Code looks like this (technically this is TypeScript, not JavaScript, the arrow functions are transpiled out):

```
directLine: DirectLine = new DirectLine({ secret: environment.botDirectLineSecretKey }) 

@ViewChild("botWindow") botWindowElement: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {

    this.directLine.activity$
      .filter(activity => activity.type === "event" && activity.name === "init")
      .subscribe(activity => this.changeSize());

    BotChat.App({
      botConnection: this.directLine,
      user: { id: 'user' },
      bot: { id: 'bot' },
    }, this.botWindowElement.nativeElement);

}

changeSize(){
    console.log("here")
    var container = document.getElementById("bot-chat-container");
    container.classList.add("fullSize");
}
```

In Internet Explorer, I get this error in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was
>   expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

If I switch `botConnection: this.directLine` to `directLine: this.directLine`, the webchat works but then the changeSize() method never gets called.

Any help is appreciated. This bot is going on a public website and IE must be supported.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried `.subscribe` before `.filter`

Comment: Thanks but no. I get this. Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
But it was worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. After reading answers and comments that were posted, I created a "vanilla" html/JavaScript version of this code and it, as stated by Eric Dahlvang above, worked perfectly. I then focused on the Angular side of things for a while.

Then I noticed one difference in my original Angular code vs my plain JavaScript version and the samples found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat. I made a simple change:

Changed this:
`directLine: DirectLine = new DirectLine({ secret: environment.botDirectLineSecretKey })`

to this:
`directLine: DirectLine = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: environment.botDirectLineSecretKey })` (note that I am now using **BotChat.DirectLine**)

and everything works. Unfortunately, I don't know why.

Comment: Good to see you fixed it. Wonder why `new DirectLine()` was not caught by TypeScript because `DirectLine` seems undefined in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions are not supported in IE:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/functions-javascript#arrow-functions

The code you've shared should work in IE if it is modified to uses actual functions:

```
    this.directLine.activity$
        .filter(isInitEvent)
        .subscribe(changeSize);

...

    function isInitEvent(activity) {
        return activity.type === "event" && activity.name === "init";
    }

    function changeSize(activity) {
        console.log("here")
        var container = document.getElementById("bot");
        container.classList.add("fullSize");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I am still getting the error. If I expand out the error message in IE, can get this stack trace: `at e.prototype.error (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js:6:4949)`

Comment: Also, I looked into this a bit more. Sorry I wasn't clear but my code is TypeScript so the arrow functions are transpiled out.

Comment: @Schwammy, it's almost impossible to help more if we don't have more information / code details. Webchat is working on IE, it's only a specific point on your side and we need more details